# Laravel и ajax запрос

Tags: laravel

Подскажите что я делаю не так. Вот есть код, который, если я вставляю напрямую в routes.php

```
routes.php
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('wallets', 'WalletsController@index');
Route::post('addwallet', function(){
          //принимаем данные от пользлвателя
            $wallet = Request::input('wallet', '+11111111111');
            $query = DB::table('wallets')->insert(
                    ['wallet' => $wallet]);
});
```

то он работает,
 а если я его вставляю в метод класса, то он не работает.
Вызываю роут вот так:
 `Route::get('addwallet', 'WalletsController@add');`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use DB;

use Response;
class WalletsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $wallets =  DB::select('select * from wallets LIMIT 20');
        return view('wallets.index', ['wallets' => $wallets]);
    }

    public function add(){

            //принимаем данные от пользлвателя
            $wallet = Request::input('wallet', '+11111111111');
            $query = DB::table('wallets')->insert(
                    ['wallet' => $wallet]);


    }
```

Вот ошибка которую выдает в консоли :

```
500 Internal Server Error   159ms   
jquery-....min.js (строка 5)
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://exchanger.local/orders/laravel/public/addwallet"
```

Comment: А что в логах пишет? Это вы нам ошибку из консоли браузера показываете, она бесполезна. Что в логах сервера и Laravel?

Comment: спасибо уже решил проблему вот таким методом `public function add(Request $request){         
            //принимаем данные от пользователя
            $wallet = $request->input('wallet', '+11111111111');
            $query = DB::table('wallets')->insert(
             ['wallet' => $wallet ]);`

Answer (score 2):

Предыдущий вариант можно было решить так

**1 Вариант**

Заменить

```
$wallet = Request::input(...
```

На

```
$wallet = \Request::input(...
```

или

**2 Вариант**

Заменить

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

на

```
use \Request;
```

**P.S.** В Laravel `Illuminate\Http\Request` используется при передачи параметра `$request` в метод контроллера (`function methodName(Request $request){}`) и запись вида `Request::get('fielld')` работать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Собственно уже ответили, но продублирую:

```
public function add(Request $request, Response $response){

        //принимаем данные от пользлвателя
        $validator = Validator::make(request->only(['wallet']), [
            'wallet' => 'string',
        ]);

       $validator->validate();

       $wallet = $request->input('wallet', '+11111111111')

       $query = DB::table('wallets')->insert(
                ['wallet' => $wallet]);


}
```